# How to properly document a S3 method of a generic from a different package, using Roxygen?

Tags: r, roxygen

I am writing a package that defines a new class, surveyor, and a `print` method for this, i.e. `print.surveyor`.  My code works fine and I use roxygen for inline documentation.  But `R CMD check` issues a warning:

> Functions/methods with usage in
>   documentation object 'print.surveyor'
>   but not in code: print

I have used the following two pages, written by Hadley, as inspiration:
[Namespaces](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Namespaces) and [Documenting functions](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/docs-function), both of which states that the correct syntax is `@method function-name class`

**So my question is: What is the correct way of documenting the `print` method for my new class using Roxygen?  And more specifically, how do I get rid of the warning?**

---

Here is my code:  (The commented documentation indicated attempts at fixing this, none of which worked.)

```
#' Prints surveyor object.
#' 
#' Prints surveyor object
#' 
## #' @usage print(x, ...)
## #' @aliases print print.surveyor
#' @param x surveyor object
#' @param ... ignored
#' @S3method print surveyor
print.surveyor <- function(x, ...){
    cat("Surveyor\n\n")
    print.listof(x)
}
```

And the roxygenized output, i.e. `print.surveyor.Rd`:

```
\name{print.surveyor}
\title{Prints surveyor object.}
\usage{print(x, ...)
#'}
\description{Prints surveyor object.}
\details{Prints surveyor object

#'}
\alias{print}
\alias{print.surveyor}
\arguments{\item{x}{surveyor object}
\item{...}{ignored}}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As of roxygen2 > 3.0.0., you only need `@export` because roxygen can figure out that `print.surveyor` is an S3 method. This means that you now only need

```
#' Prints surveyor object.
#' 
#' @param x surveyor object
#' @param ... ignored
#' @export
print.surveyor <- function(x, ...){
    cat("Surveyor\n\n")
    print.listof(x)
}
```

However, in this case since the documentation isn't very useful, it'd probably better to just do:

```
#' @export
print.surveyor <- function(x, ...){
    cat("Surveyor\n\n")
    print.listof(x)
}
```

Comment: Neat. Thank you. I'll try this immediately!

Comment: Hmm. I’d like to register an S3 method *without* exporting it. Unfortunately that generates a deprecation warning. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @KonradRudolph what does it mean to register an S3 method without exporting it?

Comment: @hadley I wanted to avoid using `@export` because then `R CMD check` complained about undocumented parameters (I hadn’t documented the method since it’s supposed to be invisible anyway). However, I cannot reproduce this now: no `.Rd` file is generated and no `R CMD check` warning is displayed for missing parameters. I probably had some empty line in the doc comment beforehand, causing an incomplete documentation to be generated for this method.

Answer (score 44):

### Update

**As of roxygen2 > 3.0.0 the package has gotten a lot smarter at figuring all this out for you.** You now just need the `@export` tag and **roxygen** will work out what kind of thing you are documenting and do the appropriate thing when writing the `NAMESPACE` etc during conversion.

There are exceptions where you may need to help out **roxygen**. An [example](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-classes) that Hadley Wickham uses in his *R Packages* book is `all.equal.data.frame`. There is ambiguity in that function name as to what is the class and what is the generic function (`all`, `all.equal`, or `all.equal.data`)?

In such cases, you can help **roxygen** out by explicitly informing it of the generic and class/method, e.g.

```
@method all.equal data.frame
```

The original answer below explains more about the older behaviour if you need to explicitly use `@method`.

---

### Original

The function should be documented with the `@method` tag:

```
#' @method print surveyor
```

On initial reading, @hadley's document was a little confusing for me as I am not familiar with **roxygen**, but after several readings of the section, I think I understand the reason why you need `@method`.

You are writing full documentation for the `print` method. `@S3method` is related to the `NAMESPACE` and arranges for the *method* to be exported. `@S3method` is not meant for documenting a method.

Your Rd file should have the following in the `usage` section:

```
\method{print}{surveyor}(x, ...)
```

if this works correctly, as that is the correct way to document S3 methods in Rd files.

Comment: Thanks, been struggling with this too, but how do you use it with a class specific [-function, e.g. `[.myClass`? This solution passes `R CMD check` without warnings but the resulting Rd tag is a mess. `@method [ myClass` becomes `\method{[}{myClass} (x, i, j, ...)`.

Comment: @Backlin What's wrong with that? That looks like the proper way to mark-up and S3 method in Rd. It will render properly in the Usage section but with `## S3 method blah blah` above the usage code.

Comment: Oh no, my bad! I was looking at the documentation in an old version of R but it renders correctly in the newer versions. Hope I didn't waste too much of your time with it.

Comment: @Backlin - no worries. Glad the Q&A was useful to you.

Comment: Great answer.  so what't the deal with `@S3method`? should I use both? is `@S3method` identical to `@export` for an S3 method?

Comment: @cboettig no, they are quite different. `@S3method` registers the method but doesn't export it so it can be called from `foo()` but not explicitly via `foo.bar()`. If you also `@export` that method then you can call it directly. Usually you don't want to export the methods just register them, but on some occasions you may want to export a method and in those cases you need both `@S3method` and `@export`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson thanks! So typically I need both `@method` and `@S3method` but not `@export`?

Comment: @cboettig Yes, `@method` is the tag for the documentation (the `.Rd` file) and `@S3method` is for the namespace mechanism. You need both these days if you have your own `NAMESPACE` file. You only need `@export` if you really want to make the method visible outside the namespace of the package.

Answer (score 3):

`@export` only works if the generic is loaded. If the generic is in another package you need to import the generic. With current roxygen this is solved with a block like

```r
#' @importFrom tibble data_frame
#' @export
tibble::data_frame
```

taken from  [dplyr/R/reexport-tibble.r](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/reexport-tibble.r) . In this example, the `data_frame` method is imported from the tibble package, and tibble::data_frame is exported. Such re-exported objects are then documented in a `reexports.Rd` file that - needless to say - satisfies R CMD check.