# How to make S3 method visible

Tags: r, object, methods

My question is almost opposite to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724815/roxygen2-issue-with-exporting-print-method). I document my package with roxygen2, and within it define an S3 generic:

```
#' @export
print.myClass <- function(x, ...) { cat("Hello there!\n") }
```

The method gets correctly dispatched, however, it is not visible for the user – despite using `@export`, the user cannot access this method directly. roxygen2 only enters `S3method(print,myClass)` in the NAMESPACE file, but does not export it.

However, some S3 generics are visible (e.g. print.table or print.data.frame). I would like my method to be also attached to the user namespace. Is there an easy way of doing that in roxygen2? I.e., forcing roxygen2 to add `export(print.myClass)` to the NAMESPACE file?