# Use Roxygen to make S3method in NAMESPACE

Tags: r, roxygen2

I want to export an S3method named [.myclass using roxygen2 and I can't see a clean way to do this.

I need NAMESPACE to have

```
S3method("[",myclass)
```

in it or the method can't be used after I require the package, but roxygen2 doesn't appear to want to help me with this.

I can force it to with

```
#' @S3method [ myclass
setMethodS3("[",
        c(x="myclass"),
        function(x,i) {
blah blah balh
})
```

but roxygen then says that s3method is deprecated and that I should use @export instead, but

```
#' @export
setMethodS3("[",
          c(x="myclass"),
          function(x,i) {
  blah blah balh
 })
```

just doesn't do it. (puts an empty export in the NAMESPACE).

I asked the author of the package and he suggested i use @method and @export, but this also doesn't work

```
#' @method [ myclass
#' @export
setMethodS3("[",
          c(x="myclass"),
          function(x,i) {
  blah blah balh
 })
```

also ends up with "export()" in the NAMESPACE

What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of posting the answer in your question you should post the answer as an answer.  There is nothing wrong with posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer:

Hadley was incredibly helpful and now I realize that I shouldn't be using setMethodS3 but instead just

```
#' @method [ myclass
#' @export
"[.myclass" <- function(x,i) { blah blah blah }
```

and then everything works great.

Comment: This changed in R 4.0.0 to be more strict