# Creating an RPackage - UseMethod can't find function

Tags: r

I'm trying on my first attempt on creating an R package. I have some functions that follows below.

```
#' @export
overview  <- function(x, ...) {
  UseMethod("overview")
} 

overview.query <- function(return.query, ...) {
```

Now when I use the `devtools::load_all()` (which loads all functions) everything works, and `overview.query` is executed when I pass an object of `class query`.

But rebuilding, and the `UseMethod` can't find the `overview.query` function anymore (all functions are thus not loaded), what have I done wrong?

Error message: **no applicable method for 'overview' applied to an object of class "c('query', 'data.frame')"**

I thought that only functions that are to be exposed to the user are to be `@export`'ed, and all other functions would still be visible internally to the other package functions.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277063/why-doesnt-my-package-function-find-other-non-export-tagged-functions

Comment: Just for the record, I encountered a version of this while deliberately using unexported S3 generics and methods. When I passed an S3 method to `lapply()`, it worked with `devtools::load_all("drake")` but not `library(drake)`. Solution: nest in another function. https://github.com/ropensci/drake/commit/e5a17410d6b5499682755d187eaaf6030096f590.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a generic function to apply to an S3 object, you need to export both the `UseMethod` statement and the function itself, as in:

```
#' @export
overview  <- function(x, ...) {
  UseMethod("overview")
} 
#' @export  
overview.query <- function(return.query, ...) {
```

which ought to eliminate the error as that method is now available to the user.

This is applicable to `roxygen2` versions 3+ (currently on 5).  See this answer for more info:

[How to properly document S3 methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22598266/2573061)