# Why doesn't my package function find other non-export tagged functions?

Tags: r, r-package

I've read most of Hadley Wickham's great book: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/, but I'm confused as to why my functions within my package can't find my other non-exported functions.

E.g I have

```
#' @export
#' @import ggmap
#' @import hexbin
map  <- function(return.query, zoom, maptype, histObj) {

  UseMethod("map")

}
#' 
map.querySold  <- function(query, zoom = 11, maptype = "roadmap") {
  My Code
}
```

Running this with a clean enviroment and loading my package generates error:

```
> map(x) # x is of class querySold
Error in UseMethod("map") : 
  no applicable method for 'map' applied to an object of class "c('querySold', 'data.frame')"
```

What is wrong and how can I fix this? I thought that internal functions where always available to all other functions within the package? 
It is not until I load all functions with `devtools::load_all(".")` that it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you haven't `@export` `map.querySold`.  Try the following:

Put `@export` right before the first `map` function.

```
#' @import ggmap
#' @import hexbin
#' @export
map  <- function(return.query, zoom, maptype, histObj) {

  UseMethod("map")

}
```

And add `@export` here

```
#'@export 
map.querySold  <- function(query, zoom = 11, maptype = "roadmap") {
  My Code
}
```

Then run `devtools::document()` and check the `NAMESPACE` file.

If this doesn't work, it might be helpful to post your `NAMESPACE`.  I am thinking you should have

```
S3method(map.querySold)
export(map)
```

Comment: Thank you! I see that the S3 method is not exposed in the way I thought it would be. Do I need to export all functions in my package (I'm thinking of a case when I refer to another simple function)?

Comment: You are welcome.  No, you do not need to export all of your functions.  Just export the functions intended for the user.  Your other functions will still work from within your exported functions.

Comment: Ahh yes. Ok, so S3 methods need to be exported also, that's what got me.