# The correct way of accessing S3methods from the NAMESPACE

Tags: r

### TL;DR version:

Why are the base R methods exported differently to the way the `Roxygen2` authors recommend you export your own methods?

### Further explanation:

This is a follow up question to the posts that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198758/roxygen2-how-to-properly-document-s3-methods) and [here](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/380). Rather than bombard Hadley with lots of questions, I figured it would be best to ask the community.

I am trying to understand the behaviour of S3method exports a little better as there seems to be inconsistency between the way the base R methods are exported and the way the `Roxygen2` authors recommend they should be exported.

For example, within the `stats` package lies the `plot.ts` and `plot.stepfun` methods, among others. You can also `edit()` or `fix()` these. However with the recommended way of working in `Roxygen2` it is suggested that you `@export` all generics and methods (Hadley's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198758/roxygen2-how-to-properly-document-s3-methods)).

So, let's say we have an object of class `my_class` and we wish to create a plot function which works for this class, `plot.my_class`. We can create the `Roxygen2` documentation as follows:

```
#' plot.my_class title
#'
#' @param x An object of class 'my_class'.
#'
#' @export
plot.my_class <- function (x, ...) # some magic
```

This generates the `NAMESPACE` entry

```
S3method(plot,my_class)
```

Now, when I install the package, I will not be able to see the method `plot.my_class` when I use `ls()` on my package position in `search()`, nor can I `edit()` or `fix()` it (I can use `getAnywhere()`). Clearly this is different behaviour to that of the base R functions since I can `edit(plot.ts)`  and see it listed within the `stats` package namespace. The only way I can see to get around this is to explicitly `@export plot.my_class` in my `Roxygen2` documentation, e.g.

```
#' plot.my_class title
#'
#' @param x An object of class 'my_class'.
#'
#' @export plot.my_class
plot.my_class <- function (x, ...) # some magic
```

Which generates the - clearly wrong - `NAMESPACE` entry

```
export(plot.my_class)
```

Hadley says that using `edit()` or `fix()` is a bad idea. I understand some reasons why that is (maybe someone can expand a little?) but they are useful for debugging purposes since the functions I am working with are very complex.

So to conclude, why are there differences in the way base R's methods are viewable and my own methods are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it’s for the same reason that there are lots of other inconsistencies in the base R packages: it is an organic system that grew over many years, and many aspects are very old and preserve compatibility with the S language.

Many of the guidelines that roxygen2 and other packages recommend have grown out of the experience gained from many years of working with R.

If the base R packages were rewritten from scratch today with no regards for backwards compatibility, they would look very different.

If you find yourself needing `edit` and/or `fix` to muck around in other peoples’ packages then this suggests that these packages have some major issues that should be resolved. Normally you should not need to do this — this is part of the reason for why `fix` is a bad idea: it’s symptomatic of an underlying problem.

In fact, even with Hadley’s recommended mode of exporting package generics it’s still possible (albeit more difficult) to hack around in the non-exported methods of the package.

Comment: That answer makes a lot of sense. I hadn't considered it in terms of backwards compatability. I simply assumed there was an inconsistency between the two methods. Thanks for your answer.