# R CMD check warning: Functions/methods with usage in documentation object ... but not in code

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I am writing a package but one persistent `R CMD check` warning prevents me from finishing the package and posting it to CRAN. I use `roxygen2` for inline documentation, although that possibly isn't the root cause of the error.

If you know what to do to remove this warning, I can quite possibly figure out a way of doing it using `roxygen2`.

**How can I remove the warning** `Functions/methods with usage in documentation object ... but not in code` **from my package checks?**

---

The `R CMD check` warning:

```
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... WARNING
Functions/methods with usage in documentation object 'names<-' but not in code:
  names<-
```

The function and `roxygen` documentation:

```
#' Updates names and variable.labels attribute of surveydata.
#' 
#' @name names<-
#' @rdname names
#' @aliases names<- names<-.surveydata
#' @param x surveydata object
#' @param value New names
#' @method names<- surveydata
#' @usage names(x) <- value
"names<-.surveydata" <- function(x, value){
    invisible(NULL)
}
```

The resulting `.rd` documentation file:

```
\name{names<-}
\alias{names<-}
\alias{names<-.surveydata}
\title{Updates names and variable.labels attribute of surveydata.}
\usage{
  names(x) <- value
}
\arguments{
  \item{x}{surveydata object}

  \item{value}{New names}
}
\description{
  Updates names and variable.labels attribute of
  surveydata.
}
```

---

I have cross-checked my documentation with the documentation for `names<-` in base R, and it seems identical:

```
\title{  The Names of an Object}
\name{names}
\alias{names}
\alias{names.default}
\alias{names<-}
\alias{names<-.default}
\keyword{attribute}
\description{Functions to get or set the names of an object.}
```

---

Related question (but I have already implemented the suggestion and still no luck):

- [How to properly document a S3 method of a generic from a different package, using Roxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6517222/602276)

---

**Where am I going wrong?  How can I remove this warning from the package checks?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not a roxygen2 problem but a problem that crops up when you have a method in your package for which the generic is in another package.  I'm pretty sure I've run into similar problems in the past but unfortunately I can't remember the solution right now :-(

Comment: I don't think you want the `@usage` section. In my Rd files of similar nature, you want usage to include `\method{names}{surveydata}(x) <- value` which *should* be produce by the `@method` section. If it isn't after you delete the `@usage` line, then add an explicit `@usage` line containing the above?

Comment: @GavinSimpson That approach seems to work, thank you. However, by default, `roxygen` doesn't generate that usage, hence the override statement. I shall report this as a bug / new feature request.

Comment: If you are documenting both the `names.surveydata()` and `"names<-.surveydata()"` in the same file, I'd add both in the `@usage`, if you are documenting them separately then it doesn't matter.

Comment: If `roxygen2` is not producing correct output by default, please file a bug report.  You also shouldn't need `@aliases`, `@name`, or `@rdname`

Comment: @hadley I have filed an issue at https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/102

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `\usage` section in the Rd file needs to include the following:

```
\method{names}{surveydata}(x) <- value
```

If this is not automatically inserted by the `@method` line (I presume that will only add `\method{names}{surveydata}(x)`?) then you need an explicit `@usage` section that includes the above. Something like

```
#' @usage \\method{names}{surveydata}(x) <- value
```

I would also change the `@name` and `@alias` sections to refer to the method explicitly not the generic as that will clash with the Rd file in R::base.

Essentially, the warning is coming from the fact that your package *doesn't* contains a function `"names<-"` yet you are using this in `\usage{}`.

Comment: +1 This seems to work - I no longer get any `R CMD check` warnings.  Thank you also for the additional tips about `@name` and `@alias`. I'll study these carefully - they most likely have been mangled in this way in my attempts to satisfy the package check mechanism!

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps anyone, this error can also arise from an abandoned Rd file for which a function or data object no longer exists.