# Document new S4 method for an existing generic

Tags: r, r-s4, roxygen2, roxygen

I would like to document a new method for the `plot` generic.
The question is, how to document a new method for a standard generic.

When running

`devtools::check(document = FALSE)`

I get the warning:

```
Undocumented S4 methods:
     generic 'plot' and siglist 'my_new_class'
```

Here is my code (R 4.0.3, roxygen2 7.1.1):

```
#' Plot a new class
#' 
#' Dummy text
#' 
#' @param x An object of class \code{\link{my_new_class}}.
#' @param y Not used.
#' @param ... Plot parameters forwarded.
#' @return A plot object.
#' @export
methods::setMethod("plot",
                   c(x="my_new_class"),
                   function(x, ...){
                     new_plot_func(x)
                   })
```

I already looked at the following similar posts, but could not adapt it to my problem:

[New method for plot - how to export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120895/new-method-for-plot-how-to-export)

[How to properly document S4 "[" and “[<-“ methods using roxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396768/how-to-properly-document-s4-and-methods-using-roxygen)

I already tried using `@rdname` and `@alias`.

Comment: A similar question was already asked in a comment of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7423698/12517337) but not answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem myself, which runs `devtools::check(document = FALSE)` without warnings.

```
#' Plot a new class
#' 
#' Dummy text
#' 
#' @param x An object of class \code{\link{my_new_class}}.
#' @param y Not used.
#' @param ... Plot parameters forwarded.
#' @return A plot object.
#' @export
methods::setMethod("plot",
                   c(x="my_new_class", y="missing"),
                   function(x, y, ...){
                     new_plot_func(x, ...)
                   })
```

Apparently, an unused argument in an existing generic has to be set as `"missing"` in `setMethod`.