# R-oxygen documentation of S3 method produces error while check

Tags: r, roxygen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Roxygen: How to properly document a S3 method of a generic in a different package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517222/roxygen-how-to-properly-document-a-s3-method-of-a-generic-in-a-different-packag)

I try to create a method as.mcmc.mcmcComposite based on as.mcmc defined in package coda.
Here is the code:

```
#' as.mcmc Extract mcmc object from a result to be used with coda package
#' @title Extract mcmc object from a result to be used with coda package
#' @author Marc Girondot
#' @return A mcmc.list object
#' @param x A result object
#' @description Take a mcmcComposite object and create a mcmc.list object
#' @examples
#' # Try
#’ method as.mcmc mcmcComposite
#' @export


as.mcmc.mcmcComposite <-
function(x) {
    return(x$resultMCMC)
}
```

It works well but produce an error while check:

```
* checking Rd \usage sections ... NOTE
S3 methods shown with full name in documentation object 'as.mcmc.mcmcComposite':
  ‘as.mcmc.mcmcComposite’

The \usage entries for S3 methods should use the \method markup and not
their full name.
See the chapter ‘Writing R documentation files’ in the ‘Writing R
Extensions’ manual.
```

I don't understand how to correct such error.
Thanks for any advice

Marc Girondot

Comment: I think you are missing an `@` in the second to last line, and you used. It should be `#' @method as.mcmc mcmcComposite`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198758/roxygen2-how-to-properly-document-s3-methods and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517222/roxygen-how-to-properly-document-a-s3-method-of-a-generic-in-a-different-packag

Comment: And on a sidenote: that's not an error. That's a note.