# UseMethod for numeric in R package cannot find generic.class

Tags: r

I am trying to have the following simple dispatch in my package:

```r
mean_freq_impute <- function(x)
    UseMethod("mean_freq_impute")

mean_freq_impute.factor <- function(x) {
    mean_freq_impute.character(x)
}

mean_freq_impute.numeric <- function(x) {
    m <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    x[is.na(x)] <- m
    x
}

mean_freq_impute.character <- function(x) {
    tab <- table(x, useNA = "no")
    out <- which(tab == max(tab))
    f <- names(out[sample.int(length(out), 1)])
    x[is.na(x)] <- f
    x
}

mean_freq_impute(c(runif(10), NA))
#>  [1] 0.3787886 0.6829136 0.5880888 0.4859935 0.4704209 0.7654958 0.7925840
#>  [8] 0.0661300 0.7238502 0.2985131 0.5252779
mean_freq_impute(factor(c(letters[1:5], NA)))
#> [1] a b c d e d
#> Levels: a b c d e
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Which I have coded in a file as:

```
#' Mean or Frequency Imputation
#' @param x The vector to replace missing values in
#'
#' @description
#' Replaces `NA` values with the mean for `numeric` or the most frequent observation for `character`.
#' For characters, ties are broken uniformly at random
#'
#' @return
#' A vector with missing values replaced by the mean or most frequent observation
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' mean_freq_impute(c(runif(10), NA))
mean_freq_impute <- function(x)
  UseMethod("mean_freq_impute")

mean_freq_impute.factor <- function(x) {
  mean_freq_impute.character(x)
}

mean_freq_impute.numeric <- function(x) {
  m <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  x[is.na(x)] <- m
  x
}

mean_freq_impute.character <- function(x) {
  tab <- table(x, useNA = "no")
  out <- which(tab == max(tab))
  f <- names(out[sample.int(length(out), 1)])
  x[is.na(x)] <- f
  x
}
```

But when I load the package I get class errors despite that it finds the methods:

```r
devtools::load_all(path = '~/Desktop/test/')
#> ℹ Loading test
methods("mean_freq_impute")
#> [1] mean_freq_impute.character mean_freq_impute.factor   
#> [3] mean_freq_impute.numeric  
#> see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
mean_freq_impute(c(runif(10), NA))
#> Error in UseMethod("mean_freq_impute"): no applicable method for 'mean_freq_impute' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
mean_freq_impute(factor(c(letters[1:5], NA)))
#> Error in UseMethod("mean_freq_impute"): no applicable method for 'mean_freq_impute' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>
Anyone knows why this fails?

Comment: comments look relevant at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74521311/no-applicable-method-for-s3-generic-despite-existence-of-default-method

Comment: @user20650 ah, got dammit, yeah.... adding the export tag fixed it. Thanks! Should I remove the question or wait for it to be marked as duplicate?

Comment: I dont think we can mark your Q as a dup as the linked Q does not have an answer. I suppose you could add an answer at the other Q and then we could

Comment: Do not export the function but rather export the generic function and then the method. ie use `exports3Method` tag

Comment: @user20650 Ok I've added an answer to the linked question. Thanks again!

Comment: @Onyambu thanks for your input. Is that the current guideline? The SO post linked's comment section suggest to only add `export`

Comment: @Baraliuh exporting the function makes it visible in the namespace. and thus accessible using scope resolution operator. But in your case, you are only interested in exporting the generic function. There are some differences. For example using export will have 4 visible functions while using `exports3method` will have 1 visible function in th package

Comment: @Onyambu Ah, I see, then I'll use your suggestion for my particular case. Thanks for making the contrast explicit.